# Deleting instances / fields - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am having some difficulties with my module I am currently working on.  As part of this module I have created a few fields that appear on a form.  This form is based in a custom entity.

First I am using `field_create_field($field);` to create the row in the `field_config` table.  I am then using `field_create_instance($instance);` to create the row in the instance table and also create the table that begins with `field_data_field`.

The problem I am running into is how to remove these tables correctly at the end.  I have tried manual deletion (via hook_uninstall), I've tried field_delete_field, I've tried to use the remove_instance hook that is built into the Commerce module.  Either way, I end up getting lots of `field_deleted_data_xxx` tables being created.  These don't even have data in them as I created a manual query to empty the main data tables before this function was called that seems to create these tables.

Has anyone else ever run into this problem?  How do I stop Drupal from creating these tables??

Comment: It's not a 'problem' it's by design...deleted data is archived in these tables. What problem are these tables causing that require you to delete them?

Comment: Well the concept may be of some use to us, it hasn't been decided fully yet.  The problem, so to speak, is the fact that it creates a huge number of tables and fills up the database.  A good piece of information would be to know whether or not I can easily re-use this data when I reinstall the module?  i.e. is there a way to quickly and easily convert all the stored data straight back into the fields and keep previous relationships assuming that the structure is maintained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop Drupal from creating them but I believe you can rid yourself of them totally using [`field_purge_batch`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_purge_batch/7) and its related functions.

I really wish I knew the answer to your second question (in your comment above), my instinct would be that if you re-attach the field to the bundle then that data would become automatically available again (otherwise it really doesn't make sense to keep hold of the deleted tables) but I really can't be sure about that.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will look into the purge_batch and also try to find out about re-using the data.  I will let you know if I find anything out!

Comment: According to http://drupal.org/node/1203876 you actually need to call `field_purge_batch` twice (minimum) to clean up after the deleted fields. This would explain what I observed when trying to do this myself. Note also that `field_cron` calls `field_purge_batch`, so if you didn't need to clean things up immediately, you might just leave it for cron to deal with in due course.